# Overwrite list when function callback

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is my code:

```
List = []

def a():
    for i in range(5):
        i = int(input('Input Number {}: '.format(i+1)))
        List.append(i)
    print('\nThanks for adding')
    return mainMenu()

def b():
    print('List value is {}'.format(List))
    return mainMenu()
```

List in global

So how to overwrite list value in len(5) if I go back to function def a()?

Comment: Are you asking about how to create a 5-element list every time one calls `a()` instead of appending to `List`?

Comment: Yes, I mean like that

Answer (score 0):

if you want to mutate/overwrite your  `List` in the function `a` you can do :

```
def a():
    List[:] = []
    for i in range(5):
        i = int(input('Input Number {}: '.format(i+1)))
        List.append(i)
    print('\nThanks for adding')
    return mainMenu()
```

in this way, you will always have after calling `a` only the last 5 inputs in your variable `List`

Answer (score -1):

```
List = []

def a():
    global List 
    List = []
    for i in range(5):
        i = int(input('Input Number {}: '.format(i+1)))
        List.append(i)
    print('\nThanks for adding')
    return mainMenu()

def b():
    print('List value is {}'.format(List))
    return mainMenu()
```

Please define the List variable as global and declare the empty List again inside the a() function

Comment: Yes List is  global ,but inorder to overwrite ,you need to declare again  inside the function

Comment: This is not true. The line `global List` is not necessary.

Comment: If you not decalre global List,List will be empty when you call in b() function

Comment: No, it will not be empty. Did you try?

Comment: Yes i tried , it shows empty , when we define List =[] inside the function for the overwrite

Comment: You confuse words. The `List` should be initialized _outside_ of any function as `List = []`, but there is no need to _declare_ it global with `global List`. The list shall be _re-initialized_ in `a()` with `List=[]` before getting the data. Again, `global List` is not needed.

Comment: Yes, but if i remove global list ,just reinitialized List inside the function , it shows empty when i call in b() function

Comment: @DYZ according to LGBE scope rules, `List` is local to `a()` as it is defined within the scope of the function and thus shadow what is defined on a higher level. Global is then required if we aim to access the external definition.